# lightning-datatable updating onsort but not rerendering

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Im having this anoying problem where the OnSort of the lightning data table changed but the data still not render. 
Below are my codes:
Please help, Thanks!
HTML

```
<lightning-datatable class="slds-scrollable_none slds-table_striped" 
                    key-field="id" 
                    data={data} 
                    columns={columns} 
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}

                    onsort={onClickColumnToSort}
                    sorted-by={sortedBy}
                    sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
                    hide-checkbox-column

                     > 
                </lightning-datatable>
```

JS

```
const columns = [

{ label: 'CRU', fieldName: 'Url', type: 'url', sortable: true, typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'CRU' }, target: '_self' } },
{ label: 'Building Name', fieldName: 'BusinessUnitName', type: 'text', sortable: true },
{ label: 'Tenant Name', fieldName: 'TenantName', type: 'text', sortable: true},
{ label: 'Project Stage', fieldName: 'Stage__c', type: 'text', sortable: true},
//{ label: 'LLW Complete', fieldName: 'LLWPercentComplete', type: 'text'},
//{ label: 'Drawings Complete', fieldName: 'DrawingsPercentComplete', type: 'text' },
//{ label: 'TW Complete', fieldName: 'TWPercentComplete', type: 'text' },
{ label: 'Project % Complete', fieldName: 'ProjectPercentComplete', type: 'text' , sortable: true},
//{ label: 'Deal', fieldName: 'DealUrl', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'DealName' }, target: '_self' } },
{ label: 'Deal', fieldName: 'DealName', type: 'text' , sortable: true},
{ label: 'Deal Stage', fieldName: 'DealStage', type: 'text' , sortable: true},
{ label: 'Area', fieldName: 'Area__c', type: 'number' , sortable: true},
{
    label: '', type: 'button-icon', initialWidth: 20,
    typeAttributes: {
        iconName: 'utility:edit',
        label: 'Edit',
        name: 'Edit',

    }
}
```

];

export default class RdcProjectList extends NavigationMixin (LightningElement) {

```
@track columns = columns;

@track data ;
@track error;
@track recordId;
@track record = {};

//@track projectCount = 0;
@track loaded = false;
@track showModal = false;

@api projectMemberOnly = false;
@api status = 'open-0'; // accepts 'open-0' or 'open-1' or 'closed-0' or 'closed-1' values

userId = Id;
_propertyId = ''; 
_propertyName = '';
_projectCount = 0;
_status = 'open'; // status for passing to getProjectsList function

//for paginator
@api currentpage;
@api pagesize;
@api totalrecords;
@track totalpages;
_isSearchChangeExecuted = false;
_localCurrentPage = this.currentpage;

//for sorting funtions
@api hideCheckboxColumn;
@api sortedBy;
@api sortedDirection;
@api keyField;
@track assetId='';

/** Wired Apex result so it can be refreshed programmatically */
@track wiredResult;


@wire(getProjectsList, { assetId: '$propertyId', userId: '$userId', status: '$_status', hasProjectMembership: '$projectMemberOnly', page: '$currentpage', pageSize: '$pagesize' }) 
wiredData(result) {
    this.wiredResult = result;
    if (result.data) {

        if (this._isSearchChangeExecuted && this._localCurrentPage === this.currentpage) {
            return;
        }
        this._isSearchChangeExecuted = true;
        this._localCurrentPage = this.currentpage;

        this.data = this.flattenData(result.data);
        this.error = undefined;
        this._projectCount = result.data.length;
        this.loaded = true;

        this.getRecordCount();

    } else if (result.error) {
        this.error = result.error;
        this.data = undefined;
        this.loaded = true;
    }
    else {
        this.loaded = true;
        this.data = undefined;
        this.error = undefined;
        this.totalrecords = 0;
        this.totalpages = 0;
    }
}
//for sorting



// for pagination
// get total record count
getRecordCount() {
    getRecordCount({ assetId: this.propertyId, status: this._status, hasProjectMembership: this.projectMemberOnly })
        .then(count => {
            if (count !== 0 && count !== undefined) {
                this.totalrecords = count;
                this.totalpages = Math.ceil(this.totalrecords / this.pagesize);
            }
            else {
                this.totalpages = 1;
                this.totalrecords = 0;
            }

            const event = new CustomEvent('recordsloaded', {
                detail: { count: this.totalrecords, tab: 'projects', page: this._localCurrentPage }
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });

}

// used to force refresh of data when changing tabs
@api
forceRefresh() {
    this._isSearchChangeExecuted = false;
    this.currentpage = 1;
}

flattenData(arr) {
    let tmpData = [];
    tmpData.push(arr);

    tmpData = arr.map(
        row => Object.assign({ 
            "Url": '/' + row.Id,
            "CRU": row.CRU__c == null ? row.Name : row.CRU__c,
            "TenantName": row.Tenant_Name__r == null ? '' : row.Tenant_Name__r.Name , 
            "BusinessUnitName": row.Business_Unit__r.Name,
            "DealName": row.Opportunity__r ? row.Opportunity__r.Name : '',
            "DealStage": row.Opportunity__r ? row.Opportunity__r.StageName : '',
            "LLWPercentComplete": row.Percentage_Complete_Landlord__c !== undefined ? row.Percentage_Complete_Landlord__c + '%' : '0%',
            "DrawingsPercentComplete": row.Percentage_Complete_Drawings__c !== undefined ? row.Percentage_Complete_Drawings__c + '%' : '0%',
            "TWPercentComplete": row.Percentage_Complete_Tenant__c !== undefined ? row.Percentage_Complete_Tenant__c + '%' : '0%',
            "ProjectPercentComplete": row.Project_Percentage_Complete__c !== undefined ? row.Project_Percentage_Complete__c + '%' : '0%',
            "DealUrl": row.Opportunity__r ? '/' + row.Opportunity__r.Id : ''  
        }, row)
    );
    return tmpData;
}

set propertyName(value) {
    this._propertyName = value;
}

@api 
get propertyName() {
    return this._propertyName;
}


// Use set and get to process the value every time it's
// requested while switching between properties
set propertyId(value) {
   this._propertyId = value;
    this._isSearchChangeExecuted = false;
    this.currentpage = 1;
}

// getter for propertyId
@api 
get propertyId(){
    if (this._propertyId === undefined || !this._propertyId)
        return '';
    return this._propertyId;
}

@api
getProjectCount() {
    return this._projectCount;
}

//option values based on project status (open/closed) and project team member (1=user is team member on project, 0=all projects)
get options() {
    return [
        { label: 'My Open Projects', value: 'open-1' },
        { label: 'My Closed Projects', value: 'closed-1' },
        { label: 'All Open Projects', value: 'open-0' },
        { label: 'All Closed Projects', value: 'closed-0' }];
}


handleStatusChange(event) {
    let opts = event.detail.value.split("-");

    if (opts) {
        this._status = opts[0];
        this.loaded = false;

        // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
        let boolMemberOnly = !!(opts[1] == "1");
        this.projectMemberOnly = boolMemberOnly;
    }


    //this._isSearchChangeExecuted = false;
    //this.currentpage = 1;

    //const evt = new CustomEvent('pagereset');
    //this.dispatchEvent(evt); 
}




get projectsExist() {
    if (this.data !== undefined && this.data !== null && this.data.length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

handleNewProjectClick()
{
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'RDC_Project__c',
            actionName: 'new'
        },
    });
}

handleRowAction(event) {
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;

    const row = event.detail.row;
    this.record = row;
    switch (actionName) {
        case 'Open':
            //this.openRecord();
            break;
        case 'Edit':
            //open modal window to edit project
            this.showModal = true;
            //this.loadProjectRecord();
            break;
        // case 'Delete':
        //     // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
        //     if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this project?')) {
        //         this.deleteProject();
        //     }
        //     break;
        default:
    }

}

@api 
refreshData() {
    return refreshApex(this.wiredResult);
}


// deleteProject() {

//     // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
//     console.log('delete project Id ' + this.record.Id);

//     deleteRecord(this.record.Id)
//         .then(() => {
//             this.dispatchEvent(
//                 new ShowToastEvent({
//                     title: 'Success',
//                     message: 'Record ' + this.record.Name + ' was deleted.',
//                     variant: 'success',
//                 }),
//             );
//             this.refreshData();
//         })
//         .catch(error => {
//             this.dispatchEvent(
//                 new ShowToastEvent({
//                     title: 'Error deleting record ' + this.record.Name,
//                     message: error.message,
//                     variant: 'error',
//                 }),
//             );
//         });
// }

closeModal() {
    this.showModal = false;
}

handleRecordSubmit(event) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
    //alert('form submit');
    event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    this.showModal = false;
    this.refreshData();

}
// loadProjectRecord() {
//     getProject( { recordId : this.record})
//         .then(result => {
//             this.assets = result;
//             this._propertyCount = this.assets.length;
//         })
//         .catch(error => {
//             this.error = error;
//         });
// }

handleSuccess() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Project updated successfully!',
            variant: 'success'
        })
    );
    this.showModal = false;
    this.refreshData();
}

handleSave() {

    const fields = {};
    fields[Id] = this.record.Id;
    const recordInput = { fields };

    updateRecord(recordInput)
        .then(() => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Project updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            // Clear all draft values
            this.draftValues = [];

            // Display fresh data in the datatable
            this.refreshData();
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
}
@api
onClickColumnToSort(event){
    var fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
    var sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    this.sortedBy = fieldName;
    this.sortedDirection = sortDirection;
    this.wiredResult = this.sortData(fieldName, sortDirection);

    this.wiredResult =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.wiredResult));

}

sortData(fieldName, sortDirection) {
     var dataToSort =(this.wiredResult);
     dataToSort=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataToSort));

     window.console.log(`parse data = ${dataToSort}`);
    let reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';//toggle previous direction on every click on column

    [].slice.call(dataToSort).sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse));
     //refreshApex(this.dataToSort);


    return dataToSort;

 }

 sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {
     var key = primer ?function(x) { return primer(x[field])} : function(x) {return x[field]};
         reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
         window.console.log('key- '+key+' ; field - '+field+' ; reverse - '+reverse);
         return function (a, b) {

             return a = key(a),b = key(b),reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));//eslint-disable-line
         }
 }
```

}

Comment: Please make sure to use relevant tags on your post, only. `salesforcedx` and `salesforcedx-cli` don't fit here.

Comment: Did you try setting the sorted data to the "data" variable instead of "wiredResult" variable and I think the sort should be against the "data" property on the "wiredResult" variable. wiredResult.data

Answer (score 0):

In your `sortData` method you are using `JSON.parse`, returning the results back to the `onClickColumnToSort` method, then doing an additional `this.wiredResult =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.wiredResult));` at the end.

Doing that twice probably won't give you the proper data format for `wiredResult`